# Should I put a space after a comma in the meta keywords tag?

Tags: html, seo, search-keywords

In some meta tags, for example, `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`, I put a space after each comma. Should I do the same for the meta keywords tag? I am asking this because I am not sure if putting a space after the comma will put a space before the following keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. You can put it. Putting an extra space after a comma provides better readability to humans and nothing else.

For example, kind of confusing:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4">
```

Now if you look at this, it provides better readability, isnt't?

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4">
```

Answer (score 1):

Both works, you use it or not. The only thing is ',' should be used to separate various keywords or values you would like to use.